# Toolbar icon for Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, toolbar

I have an old FF extension that I want to update. The problem is that the extension toolbar is no longer placed beside the address bar. I've searched a lot, and scripting seems to be the only way to do it, but I didn't find a way to make it work.

[image]

For example I have no idea how to get a reference to the nav bar.

I tried this, but no luck:

```
    var navBar = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
    if (!navBar) {
        return;
    }
    var btn = document.createElement('toolbarbutton');  
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'mybutton-id');
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1');
    btn.setAttribute('image', data.url('bulb.png'));
    btn.setAttribute('orient', 'horizontal');
    btn.setAttribute('label', 'My Button');
    navBar.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Standard addons.mozilla.org rejection canned response: *Your add-on makes it impossible for a user to permanently remove its toolbar button, which we can't allow. Inserting your toolbar button at first run is fine, and recommended, but doing so at every startup or making it impossible to move or remove it is not.*

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

You can most certanly add an icon to nav-bar. Here's the code i use:

```
function installButton(toolbarId, id, afterId) {
    if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
        var toolbar = document.getElementById(toolbarId);

        if (toolbar) {
            // If no afterId is given, then append the item to the toolbar
            var before = null;
            if (afterId) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(afterId);
                if (elem && elem.parentNode == toolbar)
                    before = elem.nextElementSibling;
            }


            toolbar.insertItem(id, before);
            toolbar.setAttribute("currentset", toolbar.currentSet);
            document.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");

            if (toolbarId == "addon-bar")
                toolbar.collapsed = false;
        }

    }
}
```

You can call this with:

`installButton("nav-bar","YOURBUTTONID");`

Remember you have to have "YOURBUTTONID" inside your `BrowserToolbarPalette`

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="YOURBUTTONID"
                   image='...'
                   class="..."
                   oncommand="..."
                   tooltiptext="">

    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

Reference : [Toolbar - Code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Toolbar#Adding_button_by_default)